# angular directive (2-way-data-binding) - parent is not updated via ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a nested directive with an isolated scope. An Array of objects is bound to it via 2 way data binding.

```
.directive('mapMarkerInput',['mapmarkerService', '$filter', '$timeout',function(mapMarkerService, $filter, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl:'templates/mapmarkerInputView.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            mapmarkers: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

            //some other code

            $scope.addMapmarker = function($event) {
                var mapmarker = {};
                var offsetLeft = $($event.currentTarget).offset().left,
                    offsetTop = $($event.currentTarget).offset().top;

                mapmarker.y_coord = $event.pageY - offsetTop;
                mapmarker.x_coord = $event.pageX - offsetLeft;
                mapmarker.map = $scope.currentMap;
                $scope.mapmarkers = $scope.mapmarkers.concat(mapmarker);
            };

            $scope.deleteMapmarker = function(mapmarker) {
                var index = $scope.mapmarkers.indexOf(mapmarker);
                if(index !== -1) {
                    $scope.mapmarkers.splice(index,1);
                }
            };

            //some other code
       )
}]);
```

These 2 functions are triggered via ng-click:

```
<img ng-if="currentMap" ng-click="addMapmarker($event)" ng-src="/xenobladex/attachment/{{currentMap.attachment.id}}" />
<div class="mapmarker-wrapper" ng-repeat="mapmarker in shownMapmarkers" ng-click="setZIndex($event)" style="position: absolute; top: {{mapmarker.y_coord}}px; left: {{mapmarker.x_coord}}px;">
     <!-- some other code -->
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input ng-model="mapmarker.name" value="mapmarker.name" class="form-control" type="text">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Description:</label>
          <input ng-model="mapmarker.description" value="mapmarker.description" class="form-control" type="text">
     </div>
     <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteMapmarker(mapmarker)">Delete</button>
</div>
```

As you can see I am binding the name and description directly via ng-model and that works just fine. The properties are also available in the parent scope, but neither the delete nor the add works (its changed within the directives scope, but not the parent scope).

As far as I understand these changes should be applied, because I'm calling these functions via ng-click and I have other examples where this works. The only difference is, that I am binding to an array of objects and not a single object / property.

I tried using `$timer` and `updateParent()` (`$scope.$apply()` does not work -> throws an exception that the function is already within the digest cycle) but with no success, so it looks like these changes are not watched at all.

The directive code looks like this:

```
<map-marker-input ng-if="$parent.formFieldBind" mapmarkers="$parent.formFieldBind"></map-marker-input>
```

It is nested within a custom form field directive which gets the correct form field template dynamically and has therefore `template: '<div ng-include="getTemplate()"></div>'` as template, which creates a new child scope - that's why the `$parent` is needed here.

The binding definitely works in one way, the expected data is available within the directive and if I'm logging the data after changing it via delete or add, it's also correct, but only from the inside of the directive.

Because `ng-model` works I guess there might be a simple solution to the problem.

**UPDATE**

I created a plunkr with a simplified version:
http://plnkr.co/85oNM3ECFgCzyrSPahIr

Just click anywhere inside the blue area and new points are added from within the mapmarker directive. Right now I dont really prevent adding points if you delete or edit these - so you'll end up with a lot of points fast ;-)

There is a button to show the data from the parent scope and from the child scope.

If you edit the name or description of the **one existing point** that will also be changed in the parent scope (bound via `ng-model`). But all new points or deletions are ignored (bound within the functions called via `ng-click`).

Comment: It would be better if you create plunker or jsfiddle to allow readers easily reproduce your issue.

Comment: if you need to use `$parent` there is generally something wrong. Other than rare occasions of needing a parent index you shouldn't really ever need to use $parent. As mentioned a demo would help

Comment: as I explained above the form field directive does not have a regular template because the template is fetched dynamcially it loooks like this: template: '<div ng-include="getTemplate()"></div>' and that creates a new child scope. I am using this for many different form fields and its definitely correct and yes a rare occasion it is needed ;-) I will see if I can make a fiddle, hoped someone has an Idea right away, because it works for all my other fields and with ng-model. I edited my question with a better explanation regarding the form field template.

Comment: I have created a plunkr wihich reproduces the issue

Comment: Looked at demo and have no idea what to do to reproduce whatever the problem is

Comment: Okay, I'll update the question and try to explain more, but it would be helpful if you provided some more information what you currently not understand. EDIT: updated the explanation regarding the plunkr example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the parent scope, you need to access it via $parent once more, 
i change

```
mapmarkers="$parent.formFieldBind"
```

to :

```
mapmarkers="$parent.$parent.formFieldBind"
```

ng-include create one more scope, so you need to access the parent once more.

http://plnkr.co/edit/27qF6ABUxIum8A3Hrvmt?p=preview

Comment: You are right, it works with double $parent, thank you so much! But do you know why ng-model works just fine without?

Comment: I also don't understand why there are two child scopes created.... with double $parent I am still accessing the form field dircetives scrope. It should be only one from the ng-include or? I would really like to accept your answer, but I need to have a better understanding of the issue, to understand if this is the right solution (I am using the form field directive for multiple fields, which are working just fine with one $parent, because I am using ng-model and sometimes ng-change in these).

Comment: angular indeed never return error even if model assign to undefined variable, which sometimes lead to headache,

Comment: some native directive for example ng-repeat, ng-include using localscope which create "local scope" inside their markup , another directive like ng-if, ng-click is not. localscope used to isolate directive scope, from parent scope.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that _one_ isolated scope is created and therefore one $parent is necessary... but not two. Also the paremter is definitely not undefined, because the data is displayed (the one existing point in the demo) and  "name" and "description" are correctly updated via ng-model. I will accept your answer, because it solves the problem and it does not seem like anybody else will answer. Maybe I will find out whats the real issue behind this, you at least gave me a hint where to go on :-)